# Console vim(x): Can I map the scroll wheel to undo--redo?

Tags: scrolling, undo-redo, mouse

It's sort-of a follow to a [recent XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1806/). I want to know whether it's possible to map the scroll wheel to undo and redo, possibly *n* undos/redos per scroll?

I'm using `mate-terminal` in MATE 1.6.x, `bash`, `vimx` 7.4, full info:

> ```
> $ vimx --version
> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 13 2014 08:56:33)
> Included patches: 1-207, 209-475
> Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
> Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
> Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
> +acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
> +arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
> +autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
> +balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
> +browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
> ++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
> +byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
> +cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
> +clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
> +clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
> +cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
> +cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
> +cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
> +comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
> +conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
> +cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
> +cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
> +cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
> +cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
> +dialog_con_gui  +lua/dyn         +rightleft       +windows
> +diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
> +digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
> +dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
> -ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
> +emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
> +eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
> +ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
> +extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    +xpm
> ```

Comment: Honestly, you should not be using the mouse for almost anything; it defeats the purpose of vim!

Comment: @GH05T That's such an 80's opinion. Mouse is a tool, so is vim. As long as these two tools work together well for someone, it's good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it works for me:

```
set mouse=a
map <ScrollWheelUp> u
map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-R>
```

But i hope this is just for fun. Must be horrible =)