# bind mouse scroll up and down

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to make it so, in the normal mode :

- `some modifier + scroll upward` triggers revert `u`
- `some modifier + scroll downward` triggers redo `<C-R>`

Edit : I do mean mouse scroll

*some modifier* being left-alt, but that's not the important part.

Is there a way to do that ?

Edit 2 : this question is a duplicate of [Console vim(x): Can I map the scroll wheel to undo--redo?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11763/console-vimx-can-i-map-the-scroll-wheel-to-undo-redo)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess:

```
nnoremap <leader><Up> :execute "normal u"<cr>
nnoremap <leader><Down> :execute "normal ^R"<cr>
```

To see all mappings, look at key-codes:

```
:h keycodes
```

Comment: <up> <down> <left> and <right> are the keycodes for according arrows ! I meant "scrolling upward" or "scrolling downward"